# Python ftp.retrbinary() does not work when called parallelized in function

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp

I am using a script to retrieve data from a ftp-server. As I want to parallelize the download, `ftp.retrbinary` is called within a function.

Atm the working code looks like this:

```
from ftplib import FTP

def download_file(file_in, target_file):
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+file_in, open(target_file, 'wb').write)
    return 0

ftp = FTP(FTP_HOST)
ftp.login(FTP_USER, FTP_PASS)
ftp.cwd(FTP_PATH)

for file_input in files_to_check:
    download_file(target_dir,file_input)
```

As soon as I want to download parallelly, the download just gets stuck and no data is transferred:

```
from ftplib import FTP
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def download_file(file_in, target_file):
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+file_in, open(target_file, 'wb').write)
    return 0

ftp = FTP(FTP_HOST)
ftp.login(FTP_USER, FTP_PASS)
ftp.cwd(FTP_PATH)

Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(download_file)(target_dir,file_input) for file_input in files_to_check)
```

Does anybody have an idea why `ftp.retrbinary` does not work for parallel downloads?

Comment: Works fine for me. Could you provide the full error stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It turned out the parallelization was the problem. Unfortunately the download just doesn't seem to start and the file size remains at zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use one FTP session for multiple parallel transfers. The FTP protocol does not support that (contrary to the SFTP for example).

You have to open a separate FTP session for each parallel job.